# Dynamic Column Name and Value into Where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a procedure that I working on and I don't know what's going wrong. I have reviewed all other sites and could not find the issue that I'm having

I want to create procedure that has a dynamic where clause base on a combination of bits being sent to the procedure. I don't want to have to create a bunch of similar procedures because they have slightly different conditions.

I'm placing the below query into a cursor then looping through the cursor. Please help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procContainTest] (
    @USE_A BIT,
    @USE_B BIT,
    @ValueA VARCHAR(50),
    @ValueB VARCHAR(50),
    @USERID VARCHAR(50)
    )
AS
DECLARE @TEMP_Col1 INT,
    @TEMP_Col2 INT,
    @TEMP_Col3 VARCHAR(50),
    @TEMP_Col4 VARCHAR(50),
    @TEMP_Col5 VARCHAR(50),
    @POINT_ONE NVARCHAR(50),
    @POINT_TWO NVARCHAR(50)

SET @TRIGGER = 0

WHILE @TRIGGER = 0
BEGIN
    -- F2 Booking Term
    IF @USE_A = 1
        AND @USE_B = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @POINT_ONE = 'ColName2'
        SET @POINT_TWO = 'ColName3'
    END

    -- F6 Booking Term
    IF @USE_A = 0
        AND @USE_B = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @POINT_ONE = 'ColName1'
        SET @POINT_TWO = 'ColName2'
    END

    DECLARE INNER_CURSOR CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT TOP 1 TEMP_Col1 INT,
        TEMP_Col2,
        TEMP_Col3,
        @TEMP_Col4,
        @TEMP_Col5
    FROM TEMP_Table
    WHERE @POINT_ONE = + '''' + @ValueA + ''''
        AND @POINT_TWO = + '''' + @ValueB + ''''
        AND USERID = @USERID
    ORDER BY LENGTH
```

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic sql to achieve this, you can't have variables representing column names - sql isn't designed to work like that.  Check out this article for more info on dynamic sql: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html.

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic SQL to do what you're trying to do. I.e. declare the `SELECT` statement as varchar, and then concat the command with the parameters. Finally, you then call `sp_executesql` to execute the full command.

Comment: I saw this question. Will this not work. [StackOverflow]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093834/creating-a-dynamic-where-clause-in-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: The answer in that question will work - but you have to add the `case` syntax to your query with appropriate modifications.  It looks like your column names are finite ('ColName1','ColName2' and 'ColName3') - so the approach could allow you to avoid dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid the use of dynamic SQL altogether.  You can eliminate your IF statements and embed the same logid in your SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    TEMP_Col1,
    TEMP_Col2,
    TEMP_Col3,
    TEMP_Col4,
    TEMP_Col5
FROM TEMP_Table
WHERE (@USE_A = 1 AND @USE_B = 1 AND ColName2 = '''' + @ValueA + '''' AND ColName3 = '''' + @ValueB + '''') 
OR (@USE_A = 0 AND @USE_B = 1 AND ColName1 = '''' + @ValueA + '''' AND ColName2 = '''' + @ValueB + '''')
```

Comment: This is the one that is more simple to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

l
You can put your Select Statmement in a variable like:

```
declare @YourSelectStatement nvarchar(max)

set @YourSelectStatement = '    SELECT TOP 1 TEMP_Col1 INT,
        TEMP_Col2,
        TEMP_Col3,
    FROM TEMP_Table
    WHERE ' + @POINT_ONE + '=' + @ValueA + '
        AND ' + @POINT_TWO + '=' + @ValueB + '
        AND USERID = ' + @USERID + '
    ORDER BY LENGTH'

sp_executesql(@YourSelectStatement)
```

Comment: This is a very simple way to perform dynamic sql. I didn't know about the sp_executesql procedure. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

this is probably help you:

```
SELECT
    id, first, last, email, notes
FROM
    My_Table
WHERE
    CASE ''''+@column_name_variable+''''
        WHEN ''''+column_1+''''=1 THEN column_1
        WHEN ''''+column_2+''''=2 THEN column_2
        ...
        ELSE 'not null'
    END IS NOT NULL
```