# Substituting value in a SQL query where Condtion

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables

### Offer

```
OfferName OfferRule

Offer 1    Age > 50
Offer 2   City = 'Bangalore' and Age < 10
```

### Customer

```
CustomerName    Age  City       CustomerActive

Customer 1       25   Pune             1   
Customer 2       75   Pune             1  
Customer 1       35   Bangalore        1
```

I need to subsstitute the Offer.OfferRule in SubQuery with the values in OfferRule of Offers table

```
Select OfferName from Offers where OfferDate > '01 Feb 2015' and 
      Exists(Select Id from Customers where CustomerActive = 1 and 
             Offer.OfferRule)
```

The query should get framed and execute as

```
Select OfferName from Offers where OfferDate > '01 Feb 2015' and 
      Exists(Select Id from Customers where CustomerActive = 1 and 
             City = 'Bangalore' and Age < 10)

Select OfferName from Offers where OfferDate > '01 Feb 2015' and 
      Exists(Select Id from Customers where CustomerActive = 1 and 
             Age > 50)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: yes it's possible, with dynamic sql, see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093834/creating-a-dynamic-where-clause-in-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: @Tanner...both my table has not relation to frame that

Comment: @jpw..the link doent load :(

Comment: @jpw..it says cannot be connectes

Comment: @jpw..thanks...can i get the matching offers in a single result table rather than multiple result table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have various offers stored in a table `offers` and a set of rules for selecting offers in the `offer` table and you want to know which offers match different rules based on information about customers.

Maybe something like the script below is what you're looking for (or at least it should give you an idea on how to proceed). Note that it's only meant as an example - there might be better ways to accomplish the same result, and I didn't test it that much.

The script below would generate an output like:

```
Offers with matching customers
------------------------------
Offer 1
Offer 2
Offer 3
Offer 4
```

The script:

```
begin transaction
set nocount on

create table #Offer (OfferName varchar(10), OfferRule varchar(50));
create table #Offers (OfferName varchar(10), offerdate date);
create table #Customers (
    id int, CustomerName varchar(20), Age int, City varchar(20), CustomerActive int);

insert #Offer values 
('Offer 1', 'Age > 50'),
('Offer 2', 'City = ''Bangalore'' and Age < 10'),
('Offer 3', 'Age = 30'),
('Offer 4', 'City = ''Pune''');

insert #Offers values 
('Offer 1', '2015-03-01'),
('Offer 2', '2015-03-01'),
('Offer 3', '2015-03-01'),
('Offer 4', '2015-05-01');

insert #Customers values 
(1, 'Customer 1', 25, 'Pune', 1) ,
(2, 'Customer 2', 75, 'Pune', 1),
(3, 'Customer 3', 35, 'Bangalore', 1),
(4, 'Customer 4',  5, 'Bangalore', 1),
(5, 'Customer 5', 30, 'Bangalore', 1)

declare @stmts table (id int, stmt nvarchar(max), offerrule nvarchar(max))
insert @stmts
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), 
    N'SELECT OfferName FROM #Offers 
      WHERE OfferDate > ''01 Feb 2015'' 
     AND EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM #Customers WHERE CustomerActive = 1 
     AND ' + offerrule + ') 
     AND OfferName = ''' + OfferName + '''', 
    OfferRule
from #Offer

declare @count int = @@rowcount, @pos int = 1, @stmt nvarchar(max)
declare @results table ("Offers with matching customers" varchar(30))
while (@pos <= @count) 
begin
    select @stmt = stmt from @stmts where id = @pos
    insert into @results exec (@stmt)    
    set @pos += 1
end

select * from @results

rollback transaction
```